# What caused the first measurement to the universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, measurements

I've been bumbling with a question recently. People postulate that with the give model of big ban, particles forms and breaks and eventually became what we saw as of today.

However, if we put quantum into the picture, the original universe seemed to be described by bunch of superposition of quantum states. But then in order for the universe to be "realized", there must be a point where such superposition and uncertainty starts to break down, either at cosmic scale or at very "small", as of a measurement.

1. Thus, what caused the first measurement that collapsed the universe into what one preserve as of today's? (is it the creation of photon or something else?)
2. Also, the photon carry the information of original universe. Dose that mean people, in the reference of earth, are still making the measurement to the universe and collapsing the universe? Or weather the universe has completely collapsed?(i.e. does this collapse happen at certain space, or happen to the universe at once.)
3. Another logic debate was that: could the first measurement happen inside the universe at all? (i.e. does this imply no causal model, or weather we need some non conservative process?)

Comment: You're asking about the *first* measurement. Why is the first one more mysterious than all the others? Are you familiar with the idea of decoherence?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Q1-3 each implied very different construction of universe and law of physics. As for the decoherence: where does your environment comes from if you don't have the first measurement?(unless you are suggesting some thing physical can survive the big bang.) If there's no "environment", what does the quantum states "decoherebce" to and with respect to what? That's why "first measurement" is so important it's like the 1 in nature number.

Comment: You seem to be stuck on a 'measurement' as an important part of the physics. At some level, this is more philosophy or opinion than physics.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm just get confused about how things become "realized".(It doesn't have to be a measurement, as Q3 has suggested.) But basically how to create a reference of which eventually leaded to an environment. Measurement just seemed to be the most "reasonable" way without, say getting involved with something that's not in standard physics textbook. I mean, every other postulates does not generate such reference/environment, thus it has to come back to measurement.(at least in standard quantum)

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453410/how-could-quantum-effects-occur-in-the-early-universe-without-an-observer/453555#453555